# What process should I follow to map Ember-Data to a series of non-standard APIs?

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data, serialization

I am starting an Ember application from scratch that will connect to many non-standard JSON APIs which I don't control and from which I only need bits and pieces of data. My first attempt was to use jQuery alone but the code quickly became hard to read and maintain.

I want to use the Ember-Data RESTAdapter with some Serializers. I may need multiple Adapters and Serializers for the different APIs.

I am trying to figure out a good way to break down the work into logical steps.

What process should I follow?

For example:

## "Start with what I need" approach:

- Model ALL my objects using the FixtureAdapter as the ApplicationAdapter
- Implement sample app using the models to ensure it's logically correct
- Switch the FixtureAdapter for the RESTAdapter
- Extend the RESTAdapter for each Model to map to the different APIs
- Create a Serializer for each Model Adapter

-or-

## "Start with what I can get" approach:

- Extend a SINGLE ModelAdapter at a time, mapping it to the necessary API end-point
- Create the Model for my ModelAdapter
- Create the Serializer for that ModelAdapter
- Implement model in the app
- Repeat

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634433/formatting-json-using-the-restserializer-in-the-latest-ember-data-version) suggests "I found it very useful first define the desired JSON and test it working first, then try to munge the real JSON into that format."

Comment: I would go with the former. You can pick and choose what you need from the APIs more easily once you have the app working with stubbed models. In my experience, this also allows you to do a pretty thorough UX review, which can lead to drastic changes in how models are represented. In turn, that can affect how you work with the 3rd party APIs.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. I just found out about normalizeHash in the documentation for [RESTSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html) which gives me confidence that step 5 on the modeling-first approach is doable.